# Feeding multiple analog video channels onto a common bus - signal integrity issue?

Tags: analog, video, rgb, transmission

Consider the following simplified schematic:

The intention here is to have multiple analog video input channels selectively coupled trough an analog switch onto a shared bus (this bus will be on a PCB). At most only one video input is selected and fed to the bus to be then buffered and amplified to be send over a video cable to be consumed elsewhere. So this is basically a n channel video multiplexer.

[image: Video bus basic topology]

The analog video signals carried over these lines can be CVBS (composite video) or one of the color RGB channels for standard definition video (I will have 4 copies of these busses, one for each of these signals).

The signal bandwidth for CVBS should be limited to at most 6MHz but for SD RGB I've seen figures around 20MHz.

Due to connector sizes, I expect this bus to have around 25cm.

Should worry about transmission line behavior here? Assuming that the maximum frequency will be around 20MHz, this translates to a wavelength of 15m.

My concerns here are around these two scenario extremes:

1. If the active video feed is the one at one end of the bus and the amplifier is at the other end, then all should be fine.
2. If the active video feed is the one nearest to the amplifier, the bus ends up being a stub and may even radiate. Will this cause ghosting on the video signal due to reflections on the bus?

Any advice would be great, even if it is to change approach and use another topology.

Thank you.

Comment: ah ghosting in analog TV is from hundreds to thousands of meters in delay spread. (you can estimate the distance EM waves travel so that the  result makes a difference within a 6 MHz bandwidth: \$\frac{3\cdot 10^8\frac{\text{m}}{\text{s}}}{6\cdot 10^6 \frac{1}{\text{s}}}= 50\,\text{m}\$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Approximately correct ballpark.

The most differences is that speed of signal is different on PCB track than in free space, and also already a quarter length signal starts to be a critical limit, so in general some rules of thum like one tenth or one twentieth of wavelength is good for PCB track length.

25cm should still not be considered as transmission line for a video signal with bandwidth up to 20 MHz.

So the idea of analog switches is quite OK.

However using analog muxes like 4051 or specific analog video mux ICs could be used, so you would bring all video inputs to a mux input and have the mux output drive the input of the buffer op-amp.

This would avoid feeding a common bus in the middle, and eliminate transmission line reflection issued.

Specific video crosspoint ICs also exist.

The signal bandwidths are also approximately correct. Sure broadcast video bandwidth is only 4.2 MHz for NTSC and 5 to 6 MHz for PAL depending on broadcast standard. But non-broadcast video sources like DVD players, gaming consoles or video cameras do not necessarily limit to broadcast standards. Their outputs may also be poorly filtered so they could contain harmonics, expected to be filtered out by the TV. So called Studio NTSC could contain as much bandwidth as needed, up to about 7 MHz as that can still go through SDI. However even if the composite video is limited to about 4.2 MHz, obviously the system has to have higher bandwidth to still pass 4.2 MHz unaltered. If you allow 0.5dB flatness for 4.2 MHz NTSC, your system needs to have 3dB bandwidth of 18 MHz. The slew rates required go abobe 50V/us. And thus will be higher for PAL or analog component RGB video.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I looked into using analog muxes but my issue with them is that they usually don't have the required number of inputs I need (10 inputs), and then I would need to cascade them which I suppose is not ideal.

Comment: Going back to my question, if I choose to stick with the described bus topology, would the scenario in point 2 basically transform the bus into an antenna, right? If so, would there be a way to mitigate this?